# How i can read attachment for outlook2013?

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin

How read file and attachment for outlook2013 since the `item.getAttachmentsAsync` not available in old versions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [getCallbackTokenAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-1.4#getcallbacktokenasync-callback--usercontext-) API to get an EWS callback token for your backend to read attachment data.